# Error while uploading existing file to google drive using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-backups

I'm using Laravel 5.4. I'm trying to upload file to google drive using

`Storage::disk('google')->put('file.txt', 'hello world')`

using above method file named 'file.txt' is created in Google Drive folder. but i have to upload an existing zip file.

I'm using the below code to upload the zip file in google drive.

`Storage::disk('google')->put('RandomFileName.zip', storage_path('app/backup.zip'));`

Zip file is created but with corrupted file having size in 50 byte sometimes.

Comment: I want to upload file to google drive do you have any way ?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by

```
Storage::disk('google')->put('FileName.zip', file_get_contents("fileLocation"));
```

Previously I was not including **file_get_contents()** that's why it wasn't including the content of the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) you should use the `copy` or `move` method, not `put`.

So your code should be something like:

```
Storage::disk('google')->move(storage_path('app/backup.zip'), 'RandomFileName.zip');
```